# Как правильно настроить if modified since по рекомендации Яндекс и Google

Tags: seo, http-заголовки

**Яндекс пишет:**
Следите за корректностью HTTP-заголовков. В частности, важно содержание ответа, который сервер отдает на запрос «if-modified-since». Заголовок Last-Modified должен отдавать корректную дату последнего изменения документа.

**Google пишет:** 
Убедитесь, что ваш веб-сервер поддерживает HTTP-заголовок If-Modified-Since. С его помощью Google может узнать, изменился ли контент сайта с момента последнего сканирования. Эта функция помогает сократить лишнюю нагрузку на сервер.

**Логика:** Чтобы ускорить индексацию новых товаров поисковиками и новых страниц, а так же переиндексацию изменений на странице, снизить нагрузку на хостинг, нужно корректно отдавать серверные заголовок MODIFIED_SINCE. Скорость навигации по сайту тоже вырастет потому что при частом открытии страниц сайта браузер уже не запрашивает с сервера страницу.

**Ошибка:** много встречал примеров когда датой обновления документа бало текущее время на момент запроса к странице. В корне не правильно, потому что в итоге вы не получаете правильной работы этих заголовков, в итоге роботы грузят каждую страницу даже не меняющуюся. В этом случае выделенные лимиты на обход будут быстро исчерпываться и индексация будет медленной.

Answer (score 1):

**Решение:**

**1.** **настроить config** (nginx в директиве server if_modified_since exact). http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#if_modified_since чтобы сервер отдавал эти заголовки браузеру и роботу поисковика.

Перезапустить сервер.

**2.** Код PHP вверху index.php

```
$LastModified_unix = $date_changed; // время последнего изменения страницы
$LastModified = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", $LastModified_unix);
$IfModifiedSince = '';
if (isset($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
$IfModifiedSince = strtotime(substr($_ENV['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 5));
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'])){
$IfModifiedSince = strtotime(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'], 5));
}
if ($IfModifiedSince && $IfModifiedSince >= $LastModified_unix) {
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 304 Not Modified');
exit;
}
header('Last-Modified: ' . $LastModified);
```

**3. Сервис проверки заголовков**: https://last-modified.com/ru/if-modified-since.html

Важно помнить: после внедрения вы получаете корректный обход поисковыми системами, но одновременно с этим страницы без изменений будут стареть для поисковых систем. Зато Вы точно будете знать что новый и обновленный контент будет быстро учтен.

Работали над магазином душевых кабин https://www.remontbistro.ru на нем реализованы корректные заголовки. Если кому что-то не понятно, пишите подскажу.

Comment: Мне кажется никакой ценности в этой информации. Так как в основном ищут как сделать lastmodify на конкретном движке. Да и ссылку на пример лучше удалить.

Comment: Часто приходится отходить от логики стандартных CMS по разным причинам, например для оптимизации скорости и производительности, разработки нового функционала и для внедрения современных рекомендаций поисковых систем. Часто приходит вывод что как будто современные разработчики не понимают или намеренно не хотят учитывать рекомендации поисковых систем по скорости загрузки страниц, разметкам документа, современных требований к юзабилити.

Comment: В итоге приходится обрабатывать напильником, а чтобы реализовать конечное рабочее решение легче на примере перепроверять через инструменты, как в итоге можно получить рост скорости загрузки страниц и полноту данных. Поделился решением потому настройка тонкая и динамически переменная то появляется то нет и чтобы разработчики, которые столкнутся с такой ситуацией быстрее решали и не буксовали.

Comment: Last modified и HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE разные по смыслу сущности: Last modified заголовок создающийся в PHP, а переменна HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE появляется после настроек сервера и я когда искал решение вводил в поиске именно как в мануалах Яндекса и Google но итогового пошагового алгоритма не находил, особенно с тонкостями отладки. Без осмысления полной цепочки настройки многие вебмастера просто не заморачиваясь вписывали текущее время запроса к документу.

Answer (score 0):

Вот сервис [if-modified-since](https://last-modified.com/ru/if-modified-since.html)

там внизу пример кода, который нужно интегрировать в свою CMS или что там у Вас. Одних настроек сервера не достаточно. Некоторые CMS, например Wordpress корректно отдают if-modified-since с модулем кеширования.